# Can not setup SSH Key correctly

Tags: git, ssh, permissions, chmod

I try to connect to a Gitlab Server and want to setup SSH for this. I followed the steps on Gitlab but the connection fails. Here my output of testing the connection:

```
$ ssh -Tvvv git@XXXX-gitlab.XXXX.com
OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1e  17 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "XXXX-gitlab.XXXX.com" port XX
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to XXXX-gitlab.XXXX.com [XX.XX.XX.XXX] port XX.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to XXXX-gitlab.XXXX.com:22 as 'XXXXXXXX'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from XXXX-gitlab.XXXX.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:uE1tRPH243kfpd9Q/MN10WAk5DsZ0tTCleo20sqQ4Vc
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from XXXX-gitlab.XXXX.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from XX.XX.XX.XXX
debug1: Host 'XXXX-gitlab.XXXX.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:p06ps84qa4QzJTeCOxlodXX/Ml2sGv8doOOdoNxpRIo
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:Sk3ubA/kcWl2l1p6OlAELC47Ra7j+7p28df/n8gGFTu
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:p06ps84qa4QzJTeCOxlodXX/Ml2sGv8doOOdoNxpRIo
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:Sk3ubA/kcWl2l1p6OlAELC47Ra7j+7p28df/n8gGFTu
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@ch-s-gitlab.ch.abb.com's password:
```

What seems suspicious is the file permissions:

```
$ ls -la ~/.ssh
total 27
drwxr-xr-x 1 XXXXXXXX 1049089    0 Apr 11 11:34 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 XXXXXXXX 1049089    0 Apr  9 17:20 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXXXXXXX 1049089  464 Apr 11 11:34 id_ed25519
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXXXXXXX 1049089  105 Apr 11 11:34 id_ed25519.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXXXXXXX 1049089 3389 Apr  9 08:05 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXXXXXXX 1049089  749 Apr  9 08:05 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXXXXXXX 1049089  383 Apr 14 08:00 known_hosts
```

I tried to change these permissions with the command  `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa*` but it does not change the output from above. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to connect using your own username (i.e. by not supplying one explicitly) and that user then does not exist on the server so it fails to authenticate. With GitLab you always establish the SSH connection using the `git` user, so in your case try to connect with `git@XXXX-gitlab.XXXX.com`.

I presume that you already added your public key to your GitLab account.

Comment: Thanks, while trying to make a minimal example I forgot this part. Unfortunately the same command with the git user gives me the same output.

Answer (score 0):

See "GitLab and SSH keys" (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/)

The steps are:

1. Generate an SSH key (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair) (if you don't already have a keypair you can use)
2. Add the SSH key to your GitLab account (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#adding-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account)
3. Test it (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#testing-that-everything-is-set-up-correctly).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Of course I already went trough the user guide. After your answer I did it again but could not figure out something that would be missing. In the testing step the above output comes out. With -Tvvv (as suggested in the guide) there are some more informations but in the end the same request to put in a password. 

The strange part in my opinion is, that my private id_rsa key does is not in the list of the  key that were tried. Do you have more knowledge about that?

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t get that. Can you please check your comment for typo or grammar, in the sentence re private rsa_id key?

Comment: Sent this one too fast... Sorry! 1. I updated in the question the output of `ssh -Tvvv git@XXXX-gitlab.XXXX.com`. To me the result still look the same. In the end it asks me for a password that does not match with my Gitlab account. 2. In line 115 `debug1: Trying private key: ...` it checks if a private key matches. There it never checks my key that is called `id_rsa`. Isn't this strange?

Comment: Ok. I see this: ‘debug1: identity file /c/Users/XXXXXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa type 0’

Comment: Yes right, but shouldn't it be in the list of the checked keys (line 115)?